# convert log4j.xml from version 1.x to 2.17.1

Tags: tomcat, log4j, tomcat9

i'm currently upgrading the log4j from v1.x to v2.17. Earlier in my application, we were using xml file. I'm not good with the configuration really appreciate the help if someone can convert the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} [%p] [%t] [%c] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="CORE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="${user.home}/my_web_trace.log" />
        <!-- <param name="file" value="d:/mu_web/my_web_trace.log" /> -->
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="2MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="30" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %t %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    
    <appender name="ERROR" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="${user.home}/my_web_error.log"/>
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="2MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="20" />
        <param name="threshold" value="ERROR" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %t %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="CORE" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="ERROR" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

i tried converting the file and not sure if this is correct:-

```
<Configuration>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{ISO8601} [%p] [%t] [%c] - %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="CORE" fileName="${user.home}/my_web_trace.log"
            append="true" maxFileSize="2MB" maxBackupIndex="30">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %t %c - %m%n" />
        </File>

        <File name="ERROR" fileName="${user.home}/my_web_error.log"
            append="true" maxFileSize="2MB" maxBackupIndex="30" threshold="ERROR">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %t %c - %m%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="info" />
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="CORE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ERROR" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: "not sure if this is correct:" : What do you observe? What do you expect? _If_ there is an error message about this configuration, it likely is not correct. If there's _no_ error message: Does it result in what you expect? Probably not, otherwise you'd not ask... But: What's missing? Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. As it is, this question is close to asking to convert the configuration for you, which would be off-topic here. But you can easily turn it around by adding information that I hinted to above (read the linked articles).